# Shellscript missing ]

Tags: bash

I have a shellscript that tells me `missing ]` in the line

```
if [ $status != "2" && $status != "3" && `echo "$temp1 > $upperLimit" | bc` = "1" ]
```

and also `missing ]` in the line

```
if [ $status = "2" && `cat motionsensordate` \> `date +%s` ]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single `[` doesn't support logical operators inside the brackets. You have to use them outside

```
if [ "$status" != 2 ] && [ "$status" != 3 ] ...
```

Use double quotes for variables in single brackets to prevent `unary operator expected` error when the variable is empty.

Or, switch to double brackets:

```
if [[ $status != 2 && $status != 3 ... ]]
```

Also, status different to 2 and 3 can be expressed by a pattern:

```
if [[ $status != [23] && ... ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you would like to (in addition to the answers here) group together conditions:

```
if [[ (  COND1  ||  COND2 ) && COND3  ]] 
then
    echo "$cmd"
    break
fi
```